# reducing the data cleaning with more efficient and faster functions

Tags: r

I have a huge df with 10 million observations and 50 variables as x. Currently I'm using "grepl", "str_replace" and "gsub" functions as follows for data cleaning which are very time consuming (each line 5 mins).

Is there any more efficient function or way to rewrite the codes to reduce run time, please?

```
 x <-x[!grepl("A",x$ITEM_1, perl=TRUE,]
  x <-x[!grepl("B",x$ITEM_1),perl=TRUE,]
  x <-x[!grepl("C",x$ITEM_1),perl=TRUE,]
  x <-x[!grepl("D",x$ITEM_1),perl=TRUE,]
  x <-x[!grepl("E",x$ITEM_2),perl=TRUE,]

 x <- x %>% mutate_at(vars(2:50), funs(gsub("\\?", "", .,perl=TRUE)))

  x$SUBNAMEZ <- str_replace(x$SUBNAMEZ,"#","")
  x$SUBNAMEZ <- str_replace(x$SUBNAMEZ,"@","")
  x$SUBNAMEZ <- str_replace(x$SUBNAMEZ,"~","")
  x$SUBNAMEZ <- str_replace(x$SUBNAMEZ,"\\(","")
  x$SUBNAMEZ <- str_replace(x$SUBNAMEZ,"\\)","")
  x$SUBNAMEZ <- str_replace(x$SUBNAMEZ,"&","")
  x$SUBNAMEZ <- str_replace(x$SUBNAMEZ,"\\\\","")
  x$SUBNAMEZ <- str_replace(x$SUBNAMEZ,"/","")
```

Regards,

Comment: Maybe just use one RegEx to rule them all? Could you provide some sample data to work with?

Comment: Are you using a loop? Your `grepl`s can be improved by using `[A-E]`, and your `str_replace` can be improved using `str_replace_all` and passing in a vector of matches and replacements.

Comment: No i’m not using a loop. It’s just a single df named x with 48 different chr variables like names, brand, status, color, ... .

Comment: What, exactly, is taking 5 minutes? Also, you can give us a sample using `dput(head(x, 10))`

Comment: In the above mentioned part, it takes 5 minutes for r to run each line mentioned above and go to the other line of code. Will try for provide some data.

Comment: With `y` a character vector, `grepl('[A-E]', y, perl = TRUE)` is some 10 times faster than the sequence in the question.

Comment: Thanks. Can gerpl or gsub be replaced with str_replace? I feel that replace Fun is much faster. Any hints?

Comment: I made a mistake, `grepl('[A-E]'` is faster but not 10 times faster. And `str_remove_all` is faster than alternatives. Also, please post a data example like @gersht said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following shows comparative timings of the OP's code in the question and a simplification of that code.
It was tested with a dataframe of `n = 10000` rows and `50` character column-vectors. The speedup is worthwhile.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(stringi)
library(microbenchmark)

fun.OP <- function(x){
  x <- x[!grepl("A", x$ITEM_1, perl = TRUE), ]
  x <- x[!grepl("B", x$ITEM_1, perl = TRUE), ]
  x <- x[!grepl("C", x$ITEM_1, perl = TRUE), ]
  x <- x[!grepl("D", x$ITEM_1, perl = TRUE), ]
  x <- x[!grepl("E", x$ITEM_2, perl = TRUE), ]

  x <- x %>% mutate_at(vars(2:ncol(x)), list(~gsub("\\?", "", .,perl=TRUE)))

  x$SUBNAMEZ <- str_replace_all(x$SUBNAMEZ,"#","")
  x$SUBNAMEZ <- str_replace_all(x$SUBNAMEZ,"@","")
  x$SUBNAMEZ <- str_replace_all(x$SUBNAMEZ,"~","")
  x$SUBNAMEZ <- str_replace_all(x$SUBNAMEZ,"\\(","")
  x$SUBNAMEZ <- str_replace_all(x$SUBNAMEZ,"\\)","")
  x$SUBNAMEZ <- str_replace_all(x$SUBNAMEZ,"&","")
  x$SUBNAMEZ <- str_replace_all(x$SUBNAMEZ,"\\\\","")
  x$SUBNAMEZ <- str_replace_all(x$SUBNAMEZ,"/","")
  x
}

fun.Rui <- function(x){
  x <- x[!grepl('[A-D]', x$ITEM_1, perl = TRUE), ]
  x <- x[!grepl('E', x$ITEM_2, perl = TRUE), ]

  x[2:ncol(x)] <- lapply(x[2:ncol(x)], function(y) stri_replace_all_fixed(y, '?', ''))

  x$SUBNAMEZ <- stri_replace_all_regex(x$SUBNAMEZ, '#|@|~|\\(|\\)|&|/|', '')
  x$SUBNAMEZ <- stri_replace_all_regex(x$SUBNAMEZ, '\\\\', '')
  row.names(x) <- NULL
  x
}

y1 <- fun.OP(x)
y2 <- fun.Rui(x)
dim(y1)
dim(y2)
identical(y1, y2)

mb <- microbenchmark(
  OP = fun.OP(x),
  Rui = fun.Rui(x)
)
print(mb, order = 'median')
#Unit: milliseconds
# expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval cld
#  Rui 17.05596 17.21667 21.41270 17.30466 17.44592  62.58906   100  a 
#   OP 42.88685 43.25211 54.68897 43.53331 43.98865 501.98495   100   b
```

**Data creation code.**

```
makeString <- function(col, N){
  y <- character(N)
  if(col == 1){
    L <- LETTERS
  }else if(col == 2){
    L <- c(LETTERS, '?')
  } else{
    L <- c(LETTERS, '@', '#', '~', '(', ')', '\\', '/')
  }
  for(i in seq_len(N)){
    y[i] <- paste(sample(L, sample(50, 1), TRUE), collapse = '')
  }
  y
}

set.seed(1234)
n <- 1e4
x <- lapply(1:50, function(i) makeString(i, n))
names(x) <- sprintf("V%02d", seq_along(x))
x <- do.call(cbind.data.frame, x)
names(x)[1:3] <- c('ITEM_1', 'ITEM_2', 'SUBNAMEZ')
```

Comment: Thanks Rui. Very good. Just a quick one: 1- how to write the grepl if instead of A-E there are different names like aeroplane, jet, Boing. 2- is there any alternative for grepl as well? 3- just out of curiosity, is there any benchmark that compares the speed of computation between r and python? Which one faster in your experience?

Comment: @Sean 1- a regex could be `aeroplane|jet|Boing`. 2- there is `stri_detect` but my tests show it's slower. 3- R or Python, which is faster? I don't know, see [1](https://www.quora.com/Is-Python-faster-than-R) and [2](https://www.r-bloggers.com/python-and-r-is-python-really-faster-than-r/)

Comment: Really appreciate it Rui.

Comment: The code for `grepl` calls out to C routines from the TRE engine and the ?regex page also suggests that the PCRE documentation may be referenced. The `stringi::stri_detect` function would be using the ICU4C library code base. I'm pretty sure that Python (which like R is an interpreted language) would be able to link to either engine, and would need to link to some engine to achieve compiled-code efficiency.